# What is the NameID in SAML used for?

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

Can anyone tell me what the exact function of the NameID is in the SAML response?

What does it represent?

Do you typically do something with it when received in the response?
We have done some implementations in the past, but we only use the claims that come along with the attribute assertion.

Answer (score 2):

It's the primary key between two systems.

Two IDP; A and B. The identity repositories underneath these are completely different.

The users in A are completely different to the users in B.

An application is protected with A but B's user's want to use it. So A and B are federated.

A user in B navigates to the app., gets redirected to A, uses Home Realm Discovery to get to B and then authenticates.

NameID is used to pass some attribute (typically email address or UPN) from B to the application. This identifies the user to the application.